# How to redirect symbol `>` to .txt in batch file

Tags: batch-file, redirect, command-line, cmd

I am trying to redirect the symbol `>` in a batch file to a `.txt` file and failing.

Example:

```
echo > > m.txt
```

So when I open the file `m.txt` I should see this:

```
>
```

Comment: you need to escape some special chars: `echo ^> >m.txt` (this is a duplicate of so much other questions...)

Comment: Thank you, you can make this as answer. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to escape some special chars: `echo ^> >m.txt`

Other characters that need escaping: `|&<>` and `%` which is an exception: it is escaped with another `%`: `%%`